# Installing a brunch.io/bower.io dependency automatically

Tags: brunch

I am new to Brunch.io.

I would like to know whether there is a command to update the top-level `bower.json` in order to install a dependency (e.g. select2).

In other words, is there a command for:

- `bower install select2`
- Edit top-level bower.json and add line: `select2":"3.4.3,`

Any clue welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know brunch.io, but with regular Bower, you use the `-S/--save` option to automatically save the dependency to `bower.json`:

```
bower install select2 -S
```